# a fourier multiplier inequality

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am reading  "Estimates for translation-invariant operators" by Lars Hormander. Currently, I am stuck at the following argument which seems obvious to Lars ))). 
Let $\varphi(\xi)$ be such a function that the following inequalities hold
$$
\left(\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}\left|\frac{\widehat{f}}{\varphi}\right|^p\varphi^2\,d\xi\right)^{\frac1p}\lesssim \|f\|_{L_p(\mathbb{R}^n)},\quad 1<p\leq 2.\\
$$
If we combine this inequality with Hausdorff-Young inequality
$$
\|\widehat{f}\|_{L_{p'}(\mathbb{R})^n}\lesssim \|f\|_{L_p(\mathbb{R}^n)},\quad 1\leq p \leq 2
$$
 and use Holder inequality, then it is possible to obtain the following estimate
$$
\left(\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}\left|\widehat{f}\varphi^{\frac1r-\frac1{p'}}\right|^r\,d\xi\right)^{\frac1r}\lesssim \|f\|_{L_p(\mathbb{R}^n)},\quad 1\leq p \leq r \leq p'.
$$
Why is it true? Please, help me.